# Как прочитать массив объектов из колонки jsonb в Spring data?

Tags: java, postgresql, spring, spring-data, jsonb

У меня есть в бд поле типа `jsonb`, состоящее из массива объектов.

`Jpa` не совсем работает с таким типом данных, то есть например, если мне нужно найти все объекты в этом `json` по какому-то критерию, то просто так я не смогу через `JpaRepository` вернуть `List` этих объектов, нужно будет сначала вернуть `List<Object>`. И далее уже через `mapper` конвертировать в нужную мне модель. Понятно, что не совсем сложная операция. Но я решил пойти дальше и попробовать такое: может как-то можно унаследоваться от какого-нибудь класса `Spring Jpa`, чтобы реализовать точно такое же поведение, но в своей реализации, то есть сразу пишет `@Query` как обычно и возвращаем например `List<Интересующая модель>`. То есть конвертация происходит в моей реализации. Может метод помечать новой аннотацией, например `@JsonToList` и параметр как раз необходимый тип модели.

У меня вопрос к более опытным джавистам, вообще такое возможно? Стоит ли пыжиться? Может скажете, что как раз это нерентабельно и заморачиваться не нужно, проще сделать класс хэлпер и через него переводить.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

В `PostgreSQL` прочитать массив объектов из колонки `jsonb` можно с помощью встроенной функции [jsonb_array_elements](https://postgrespro.ru/docs/postgrespro/current/functions-json). Далее поля объектов разложить по отдельным колонкам и выгрузить их в `java` в виде `List<Map<String, Object>>` с помощью метода [queryForList](https://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/current/javadoc-api/org/springframework/jdbc/core/JdbcTemplate.html#queryForList-java.lang.String-) класса `JdbcTemplate`.

См. [Query for array elements inside JSON type](https://stackoverflow.com/q/22736742/11141611)

---

**Пример:** в таблице `sql` в колонке типа `jsonb` могут находиться массивы объектов или просто объекты:

```
id (serial) | jsonb_column (jsonb)
------------|---------------------
1           | {"id": 1, "profit": 100, "person": {"age": 21, "name": "john"}}
------------|---------------------
2           | [
            |  {"id": 2, "profit": 200, "person": {"age": 22, "name": "petr"}}, 
            |  {"id": 3, "profit": 300, "person": {"age": 23, "name": "sidr"}}
            | ]
```

SQL запрос:

```sql
SELECT
    nt.id,
    nt.jsonb_column -> 'id' AS json_id,
    nt.jsonb_column -> 'profit' AS profit,
    nt.jsonb_column -> 'person' -> 'age' AS person_age,
    nt.jsonb_column -> 'person' -> 'name' AS person_name
FROM
(
    SELECT id, jsonb_column
    FROM public.newtable
    WHERE jsonb_typeof(jsonb_column) = 'object'

    UNION ALL

    SELECT id, jsonb_array_elements(jsonb_column) AS jsonb_column
    FROM public.newtable
    WHERE jsonb_typeof(jsonb_column) = 'array'
) AS nt
```

Возвращаемая таблица значений:

```
| id | json_id | profit | person_age | person_name |
|----|---------|--------|------------|-------------|
| 1  | 1       | 100    | 21         | "john"      |
| 2  | 2       | 200    | 22         | "petr"      |
| 2  | 3       | 300    | 23         | "sidr"      |
```

Вызов из `java`:

```java
@Autowired
private JdbcTemplate jdbcTemplate;

public List<?> executeQueryForList(String query) throws DataAccessException {
    return jdbcTemplate.queryForList(query);
}
```

Возвращаемый тип данных: `List<Map<String, Object>>`.